# Making a calculation with high precision

Tags: numerics, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

I would like to make the following calculation:

```
1/Sqrt[1 - (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16.)] - 1
```

*Mathematica* 8 returns 0. The result is obviously not 0, but my calculation must be losing precision. How can I compute this value with sufficient precision?

Comment: Just remove the `.` after 16

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the sake of alternatives, here's another way.  You can specify a precision with a backtick.  This is called an "arbitrary-precision" number.  Such numbers are treated differently than machine precision numbers.

Examples of 3 and 5 digits of precision:

```
16.`3
```

> ```
> 16.0
> ```

```
16.`5
```

> ```
> 16.000
> ```

Machine precision depends on the machine, but it's often nearly 16 digits.

```
$MachinePrecision
```

> ```
> 15.9546
> ```

The results of your calculation at different precisions are given below.  Note they are more accurate than machine precision, even though the specified precisions are technically less.  That's because *Mathematica* can use up to `$MaxExtraPrecision` [extra digits of precision in its internal calculations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html).

```
1/Sqrt[1 - (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16.`3)] - 1
1/Sqrt[1 - (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16.`4)] - 1
1/Sqrt[1 - (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16.`5)] - 1
1/Sqrt[1 - (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16.`15)] - 1
```

> ```
> 1.3*10^-17    
> 1.25*10^-17  
> 1.250*10^-17  
> 1.2500000000000*10^-17
> ```

Which way is better, this one or using `N` and exact numbers as in the answers of @chuy and @m_goldberg?  Well it depends. Normally `N[exact]` is sufficient, although in this case, it fails -- it gives `0`.  Arbitrary-precision calculations take longer, but *Mathematica* does try to keep track of the precision as it goes along.  On the other hand, [`N[exact, prec]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionCalculations.html) (@m_goldberg's answer) tracks the precision and, more importantly, it gives an answer with the target precision, if the internal precision limit `$MaxExtraPrecision` is not exceeded.

---

**Update: Alternative approach**

The difficulty in this calculation is a classic problem in numerical analysis, so please forgive me if this is well-known.  The reason can be seen in the numerator of
$${1 \over \sqrt{1-a}} -1 = {1 - \sqrt{1 - a} \over \sqrt{1 -a}} \,.$$
If $a$ is very small, then we're subtracting two numbers close to one another, resulting in a loss pf precision.  In fact, $\sqrt{1 - a}$ may be equal to $1$ when rounded to machine precision.  A solution is to rationalize the numerator to get
$${a \over \big(1 + \sqrt{1 - a} \big) \sqrt{1 -a}}
 = {a \over 1-a+\sqrt{1-a}}\,.$$
In this form, it evaluates with machine precision without a problem.

```
a/(1 + Sqrt[1 - a] - a) /. a -> (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16.)
```

> ```
> 1.25*10^-17
> ```

Even `N` has less trouble with this form.  Here we limit the extra precision to force the difficulty earlier:

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 4}, 
 N[a/(1 + Sqrt[1 - a] - a) /. a -> (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16), 20]]
```

> ```
> 1.2500000000000000234*10^-17
> ```

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 4}, 
 N[1/Sqrt[1 - a] - 1 /. a -> (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16), 20]]
```

> ```
> N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 4.` reached while evaluating -1+200000000/Sqrt[39999999999999999]. >>
>
> 1.250000*10^-17
> ```

This same problem occurs in simple arithmetic:

```
1. - 1. + 10.^-16
1. + 10.^-16 - 1.
```

> ```
> 1.*10^-16   
> 0.
> ```

In sum, another solution would be to choose a formula that avoids such numerical problems.  (I don't know of a way to get *Mathematica* to figure this out automatically.)  While it is rare that `N` cannot handle a computation, machine precision calculations are fast and to be desired if possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! There is really usefull information in your answer! Thank's!

Comment: @Thanos Thanks.  I added another solution that in some ways is better but more work for the user, and I hope I made it clear that I prefer m_goldberg's way of dealing with the given calculation

Comment: In particular, `$MachineEpsilon` is the smallest `h` such that `1. + h - 1.` is nonzero. Smaller than that (as in Michael's example), and you get *subtractive cancellation*.

Answer (score 5):

Ditch the decimal point after the 16 (this makes it a machine precision number):

`1/Sqrt[1 - (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16)] - 1`

yeilds:

`-1 + 200000000/Sqrt[39999999999999999]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! If I remove the `.` I don't get an actual number. I just need better precision.

Comment: What do you mean you don't get an actual number, @Thanos? This is a number, symbolically presented. I suppose you will say that `Sqrt[2]` is not a number, too? In any event, look up `N[]`, and note well what its second argument does.

Comment: @J.M.: he he he! It is a true number indeed! all I need is something in the format `1e-95` or something like that.

Comment: Hence my third sentence, @Thanos. Did you read the docs already?

Comment: @Thanos, then it seems you don't want the _maximum_ precision (which your question explicitly asks for).

Answer (score 5):

In V11.0 we try:

```
N[1/Sqrt[1 - (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16)] - 1]
```

we get an answer of 0.

As Michael E2 points out we are getting subtractive cancellation causing the loss of significant digits.

So we say

$$a=\frac{22500}{10^4 \left(9 \cdot 10^{16}\right)}$$

In numerical work the Taylor Series is your friend, it is used often. We will try to get a better answer just with a series. We expand a around 0.

```
Series[1/Sqrt[1 - a] - 1, {a, 0, 3}]//Normal
```

yields $\frac{5 a^3}{16}+\frac{3 a^2}{8}+\frac{a}{2}$

This is numerically very stable as it has small numerators and no subtraction of nearly equal quantities. We Hornerize it by using

```
HornerForm[a/2 + (3 a^2)/8 + (5 a^3)/16]
```

yields $a (1/2 + (3/8 + (5 a)/16) a) $

```
N[a (1/2 + (3/8 + (5 a)/16) a) /. a -> (22500 10^(-4))/(9 10^16)]
```

yields $$1.25 \cdot 10^{-17}$$

A better answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a high-precision approximation by using `N` with two arguments, the second argument specifying the precision you desire.

```
a = 1/Sqrt[1 - (150^2 10^(-4))/(9 10^16)] - 1;
Table[ N[a, p], {p, 17, 22}] // TableForm
```

> 1.2500000000000000*10^-17
>   1.25000000000000002*10^-17
>   1.250000000000000023*10^-17
>   1.2500000000000000234*10^-17
>   1.25000000000000002344*10^-17
>   1.250000000000000023438*10^-17

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!