# How to deal with loss of significance in the case $f(x) = \sqrt{x+2} -\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I would like to evaluate the expression $f(x) = \sqrt{x+2} -\sqrt{x}$ with cases when $x = 3.2 \times 10^{30}$ and $x= 3.2 \times 10^{16}$. I tried using `N[Sqrt[x+2] - Sqrt[x], 100]` and

`ScientificForm[Sqrt[x+2] - Sqrt[x], 100]`, both yielding 0 as an output. How can I obtain the desired output?

I also tried the method in [Making a calculation with high precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25736/making-a-calculation-with-high-precision) by applying `` .`100 `` as a suffix but my mathematica 12 doesn't seem to be recognizing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By using arbitrary precision numbers instead of machine numbers:

```
x = 3.2`100 10^30;
Sqrt[x + 2] - Sqrt[x]
```

> 5.59016994374947424102293417182731712454783504367865447721289523170435
>   *10^-16

Or, even better, by using exact numbers and by doing the conversion afterwards (this forces Mathematica to compute all 100 leading digits):

```
x = 32/10 10^30;
N[Sqrt[x + 2] - Sqrt[x],100]
```

> 5.590169943749474241022934171827317124547835043678654477212895231704350107190085921247950310402211757*10^-16

Answer (score 19):

Your expression can be written in a more numerically stable form:

```
Sqrt[x + 2] - Sqrt[x] == 2/(Sqrt[x + 2] + Sqrt[x]) // FullSimplify
(* True *)
```

This evaluates without significant loss of precision.

```
2/(Sqrt[x + 2] + Sqrt[x]) /. x -> N[32*^15]
(* 5.59017*10^-9 *)

2/(Sqrt[x + 2] + Sqrt[x]) /. x -> N[32*^15, 30]
(* 5.59016994374947415367652880074*10^-9 *)
```

Comment: I assume that it's numerically more stable because you're not subtracting two large numbers from each other?

Comment: @march That's what I meant.

Answer (score 10):

Use the asymptotic form of the function, i.e.

```
Normal@Series[Sqrt[x + 2] - Sqrt[x], {x, ∞, 2}]
% /. x -> 3.2*10^30
(* -(1/(2 x^(3/2))) + 1/Sqrt[x] *)
(* 5.59017*10^-16 *)
```

Note that we don't even need the second term to this level of precision:

```
Normal@Series[Sqrt[x + 2] - Sqrt[x], {x, ∞, 1}]
% /. x -> 3.2*10^30
(* 1/Sqrt[x] *)
(* 5.59017*10^-16 *)
```

Comment: First I was going to do @mikado's, then I was going to do this but played with it too long. +1 :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 This is a surprising question in the sense that such a simple thing has invited four useful (and pretty different) answers.

Answer (score 7):

Replace your approximate input with exact rational numbers, reduce the result to a single exact algebraic number, and evaluate that numerically.

```
f[xx_] := With[{x = Rationalize[xx, 0]}, N[RootReduce[Sqrt[x + 2] - Sqrt[x]]]]
f[3.2 10^30]
(* 5.59017*10^-16 *)
```